# remove date from file names for many files in a directory

Tags: bash, unix

I want to remove date from a list of file names

the file names look like this

```
data file-file201409.txt

info data file 2014-10.txt
```

And the result I want is

```
data file-file.txt

info data file.txt
```

Here is what I tried

```
for f in $previous_folder/*.txt; do
  echo "$f"
   mv "$f" "${f#*.txt}"
done
```

But it doesn't quite work

I'm new to linux, please help me.

Comment: Take a look at the `rename` command, which allows you to use Perl regular expression substitutions when renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try the below `rename` command.

```
rename 's/ *[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}(?=\.txt$)//' $previous_folder/*.txt
```

`-?` turn `-` as optional. `[0-9]{4}` Matches exactly four digits.

`(?=\.txt$)` This [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) asserts that the match must be followed by `.txt`. It won't consume any characters but asserts where the match to be happen.

Comment: this also removes the .txt extension, but I want to keep the extension

Comment: Thank you very much!!Do you mind explain the part you just added?

Comment: added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter expansion with extended globbing:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for file in 'data file-file201409.txt' 'info data file 2014-10.txt' ; do
    mv "$file" "${file%%+([-0-9 ]).txt}".txt
done
```

`[-0-9 ]` matches digits, space, and dash. `+(...)` means there can be one or more matching characters. `%%` deletes the longest matching string from the end.